# M1 MacBook runs out of battery while sleeping

Tags: hibernate, apple-silicon

My MacBook(MacBook Pro M1 Max 16-inch, 2021, Monterey v12.0.1) runs out of battery while sleeping. When I run

```
pmset -g log
```

the following log appears repeatedly while sleeping.

I unchecked Contact in iCloud settings. But this didn't work.

Every Monday the battery is completely drained again.

What is the cause and how to fix it?

```
DriverReason:smc.70070000 - DriverDetails:                                 
DriverReason:wifibt - DriverDetails:                                       
DriverReason:bluetooth-pcie - DriverDetails:                               
2022-01-15 10:23:00 +0900 HibernateStats        hibmode=3 standbydelaylow=0 standbydelayhigh=0                                        15321         
2022-01-15 10:23:00 +0900 WakeTime              WakeTime: 0.164 sec                                                                   
2022-01-15 10:23:00 +0900 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Sleep notifications: [AppleH13CamIn driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(103 ms)] [AppleH13CamIn driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(1070 ms)] [AppleH13CamIn driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(109 ms)] [H11ANEIn driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(112 ms)] 
2022-01-15 10:23:00 +0900 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(52 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(101 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(129 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(125 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(162 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(61 ms)] [AppleH13CamIn driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(1094 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(52 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(103 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(129 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(125 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(163 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(51 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(103 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(131 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(128 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(160 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(52 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(102 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(134 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(127 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(160 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(65 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(51 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(102 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(123 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(128 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(161 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(58 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(51 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(102 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(129 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(124 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(163 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(68 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(50 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(103 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(129 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(125 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(159 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(61 ms)] [AppleSN012776Amp driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(54 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(52 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(103 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(134 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(125 ms)]           
2022-01-15 10:23:02 +0900 Assertions            PID 263(mDNSResponder) Released MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:01  id:0x0xd00009c70 [System: PrevIdle SysAct SRPrevSleep IPushSrvc kCPU]          
2022-01-15 10:23:45 +0900 Assertions            PID 111(powerd) Released InternalPreventSleep "PM configd - Wait for Device enumeration" 00:00:45  id:0x0xd00009c71 [System: SysAct]          
2022-01-15 10:23:45 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:26%) 8 secs    
2022-01-15 10:23:47 +0900 Wake Requests         [*process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=5353 wakeAt=2022-01-15 11:53:00 info="DHCP lease renewal"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=246616 wakeAt=2022-01-18 06:54:03]           
2022-01-15 10:23:47 +0900 PM Client Acks        Delays to Sleep notifications: [com.apple.bluetooth.sleep is slow(1540 ms)]           
2022-01-15 10:23:53 +0900 Assertions            PID 263(mDNSResponder) Created MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00009c7f [System: SysAct]          
2022-01-15 10:23:53 +0900 Assertions            PID 111(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "PM configd - Wait for Device enumeration" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00009c80 [System: SysAct]          
2022-01-15 10:23:53 +0900 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt bluetooth-pcie/ Using BATT (Charge:26%) 45 secs   
2022-01-15 10:23:53 +0900 WakeDetails           DriverReason:SMC.OutboxNotEmpty - DriverDetails:                           
DriverReason:smc.70070000 - DriverDetails:                                 
DriverReason:wifibt - DriverDetails:                                       
DriverReason:bluetooth-pcie - DriverDetails:                               
2022-01-15 10:23:53 +0900 HibernateStats        hibmode=3 standbydelaylow=0 standbydelayhigh=0                                        15322         
2022-01-15 10:23:53 +0900 WakeTime              WakeTime: 0.182 sec                                                                   
2022-01-15 10:23:53 +0900 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Sleep notifications: [AppleH13CamIn driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(103 ms)] [AppleH13CamIn driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(1070 ms)] [AppleH13CamIn driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(109 ms)] [H11ANEIn driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(112 ms)] 
2022-01-15 10:23:53 +0900 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(52 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(101 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(129 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(125 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(162 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(61 ms)] [AppleH13CamIn driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(1094 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(52 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(103 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(129 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(125 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(163 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(51 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(103 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(131 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(128 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(160 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(52 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(102 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(134 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(127 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(160 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(65 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(51 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(102 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(123 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(128 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(161 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(58 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(51 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(102 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(129 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(124 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(163 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(68 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(50 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(103 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(129 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(125 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(159 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(61 ms)] [AppleSN012776Amp driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(54 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(52 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(103 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(134 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(125 ms)]           
2022-01-15 10:23:53 +0900 Assertions            PID 263(mDNSResponder) Released MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00009c7f [System: PrevIdle SysAct SRPrevSleep IPushSrvc kCPU]          
2022-01-15 10:24:08 +0900 Assertions            PID 852(SubmitDiagInfo) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.SubmitDiagInfo" 00:00:14  id:0x0x100009c88 [System: SysAct SRPrevSleep kCPU]          
2022-01-15 10:24:13 +0900 Assertions            PID 75336(runningboardd) Created SystemIsActive "xpcservice<com.apple.news.widget([daemon<com.apple.chronod>:35840])>75336-35840-2200:[news.widget-336D4E9ACAFE]" 00:00:00  id:0x0xc00009c94 [System: SysAct SRPrevSleep kCPU]          
2022-01-15 10:24:14 +0900 Assertions            PID 75336(runningboardd) Created SystemIsActive "daemon<com.apple.parsec-fbf>75336-40629-2201:com.apple.CFNetwork.StorageDB" 00:00:00  id:0x0xc00009c95 [System: SysAct SRPrevSleep kCPU]          
2022-01-15 10:24:15 +0900 Assertions            PID 75336(runningboardd) Released SystemIsActive "daemon<com.apple.parsec-fbf>75336-40629-2201:com.apple.CFNetwork.StorageDB" 00:00:01  id:0x0xc00009c95 [System: SysAct SRPrevSleep kCPU]          
2022-01-15 10:24:15 +0900 Assertions            PID 75336(runningboardd) Released SystemIsActive "xpcservice<com.apple.news.widget([daemon<com.apple.chronod>:35840])>75336-35840-2202:[news.widget-336D4E9ACAFE]" 00:00:02  id:0x0xc00009c94 [System: SysAct SRPrevSleep kCPU]          
2022-01-15 10:24:22 +0900 Assertions            PID 140(apsd) Released ApplePushServiceTask "com.apple.apsd-recreatecourierstate-push.apple.com" 00:00:10  id:0x0xb00009c93 [System: SysAct SRPrevSleep kCPU]          
2022-01-15 10:24:38 +0900 Assertions            PID 111(powerd) Released InternalPreventSleep "PM configd - Wait for Device enumeration" 00:00:45  id:0x0xd00009c80 [System: SysAct]          
2022-01-15 10:24:38 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:25%) 7 secs    
2022-01-15 10:24:39 +0900 Wake Requests         [*process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=5306 wakeAt=2022-01-15 11:53:06 info="DHCP lease renewal"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=246564 wakeAt=2022-01-18 06:54:03]           
2022-01-15 10:24:39 +0900 PM Client Acks        Delays to Sleep notifications: [com.apple.bluetooth.sleep is slow(1547 ms)]           
2022-01-15 10:24:45 +0900 Assertions            PID 263(mDNSResponder) Created MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00009c98 [System: SysAct]          
2022-01-15 10:24:45 +0900 Assertions            PID 111(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "PM configd - Wait for Device enumeration" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00009c99 [System: SysAct]          
2022-01-15 10:24:45 +0900 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt bluetooth-pcie/ Using BATT (Charge:25%) 45 secs   
2022-01-15 10:24:45 +0900 WakeDetails           DriverReason:SMC.OutboxNotEmpty - DriverDetails:
```

Is the problem "Wake for network access" setting?

[image: System Preferences - Battery pane]

I turned off "Wake for network access" setting.
And I ran the commands below.

```
$ sudo pmset -b tcpkeepalive 0
$ sudo pmset -b standbydelaylow 3600
$ sudo pmset -b standbydelayhigh 3600
```

Since then, the log has been changed as follows.
It still seems like something wakes up every minute though.

```
DriverReason:nub-spmi0.0x02 - DriverDetails:                               
DriverReason:rtc - DriverDetails:                                          
2022-01-16 12:10:35 +0900 HibernateStats        hibmode=3 standbydelaylow=0 standbydelayhigh=0                                        15748         
2022-01-16 12:10:35 +0900 WakeTime              WakeTime: 0.154 sec                                                                   
2022-01-16 12:10:35 +0900 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Sleep notifications: [AppleH13CamIn driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(1067 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(97 ms)] 
2022-01-16 12:10:35 +0900 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(52 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(103 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(126 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(130 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(160 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(98 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(53 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(103 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(132 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(128 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(156 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(100 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(51 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(102 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(126 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(132 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(159 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(98 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(52 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(103 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(132 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(127 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(158 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(105 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(53 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(103 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(133 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(128 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(160 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(99 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(51 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(103 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(134 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(129 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(155 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(100 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(51 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(102 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(132 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(127 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(159 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(104 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(52 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(102 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(129 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(135 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(159 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(108 ms)]           
2022-01-16 12:10:35 +0900 Assertions            PID 240(mDNSResponder) Released MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00008d9d [System: PrevIdle SRPrevSleep kCPU]          
2022-01-16 12:10:51 +0900 Assertions            PID 140(apsd) Released InteractivePushServiceTask "com.apple.apsd-requestkeepaliveproxy-push.apple.com" 00:00:16  id:0x0x1200008d9b [System: SRPrevSleep kCPU]          
2022-01-16 12:11:20 +0900 Assertions            PID 111(powerd) Released InternalPreventSleep "PM configd - Wait for Device enumeration" 00:00:45  id:0x0xd00008d9e [System: No Assertions]          
2022-01-16 12:11:20 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=disabled Using Batt (Charge:76%) 1 secs    
2022-01-16 12:11:21 +0900 Assertions            PID 240(mDNSResponder) Created MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00008da5 [System: No Assertions]          
2022-01-16 12:11:21 +0900 Assertions            PID 111(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "PM configd - Wait for Device enumeration" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00008da6 [System: No Assertions]          
2022-01-16 12:11:21 +0900 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to NUB.SPMISw3IRQ nub-spmi0.0x02 rtc/ Using BATT (Charge:76%) 45 secs   
2022-01-16 12:11:21 +0900 WakeDetails           DriverReason:NUB.SPMISw3IRQ - DriverDetails:                               
DriverReason:nub-spmi0.0x02 - DriverDetails:                               
DriverReason:rtc - DriverDetails:                                          
2022-01-16 12:11:21 +0900 HibernateStats        hibmode=3 standbydelaylow=0 standbydelayhigh=0                                        15749         
2022-01-16 12:11:21 +0900 WakeTime              WakeTime: 0.158 sec                                                                   
2022-01-16 12:11:21 +0900 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Sleep notifications: [AppleH13CamIn driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(1067 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(97 ms)] 
2022-01-16 12:11:21 +0900 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(52 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(103 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(126 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(130 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(160 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(98 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(53 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(103 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(132 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(128 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(156 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(100 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(51 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(102 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(126 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(132 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(159 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(98 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(52 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(103 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(132 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(127 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(158 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(105 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(53 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(103 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(133 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(128 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(160 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(99 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(51 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(103 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(134 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(129 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(155 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(100 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(51 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(102 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(132 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(127 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(159 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(104 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(52 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(102 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(129 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(135 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(159 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(108 ms)]           
2022-01-16 12:11:21 +0900 Assertions            PID 240(mDNSResponder) Released MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00008da5 [System: PrevIdle SRPrevSleep kCPU]          
2022-01-16 12:11:36 +0900 Assertions            PID 140(apsd) Released InteractivePushServiceTask "com.apple.apsd-requestkeepaliveproxy-push.apple.com" 00:00:16  id:0x0x1200008da4 [System: SRPrevSleep kCPU]          
2022-01-16 12:12:06 +0900 Assertions            PID 111(powerd) Released InternalPreventSleep "PM configd - Wait for Device enumeration" 00:00:45  id:0x0xd00008da6 [System: No Assertions]          
2022-01-16 12:12:06 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=disabled Using Batt (Charge:76%) 1 secs    
2022-01-16 12:12:07 +0900 Assertions            PID 240(mDNSResponder) Created MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00008daf [System: PrevIdle]          
2022-01-16 12:12:07 +0900 Assertions            PID 111(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "PM configd - Wait for Device enumeration" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00008db0 [System: PrevIdle]          
2022-01-16 12:12:07 +0900 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to NUB.SPMISw3IRQ nub-spmi0.0x02 rtc/ Using BATT (Charge:76%) 45 secs   
2022-01-16 12:12:07 +0900 WakeDetails           DriverReason:NUB.SPMISw3IRQ - DriverDetails:                               
DriverReason:nub-spmi0.0x02 - DriverDetails:                               
DriverReason:rtc - DriverDetails:                                          
2022-01-16 12:12:07 +0900 HibernateStats        hibmode=3 standbydelaylow=0 standbydelayhigh=0                                        15750         
2022-01-16 12:12:07 +0900 WakeTime              WakeTime: 0.162 sec                                                                   
2022-01-16 12:12:07 +0900 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Sleep notifications: [AppleH13CamIn driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(1067 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(97 ms)] 
2022-01-16 12:12:07 +0900 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(52 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(103 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(126 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(130 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(160 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(98 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(53 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(103 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(132 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(128 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(156 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(100 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(51 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(102 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(126 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(132 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(159 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(98 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(52 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(103 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(132 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(127 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(158 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(105 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(53 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(103 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(133 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(128 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(160 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(99 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(51 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(103 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(134 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(129 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(155 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(100 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(51 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(102 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(132 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(127 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(159 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(104 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(52 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(102 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(129 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(135 ms)] [RTBuddyV2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(159 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(108 ms)]           
2022-01-16 12:12:07 +0900 Assertions            PID 240(mDNSResponder) Released MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00008daf [System: PrevIdle SRPrevSleep kCPU]          
2022-01-16 12:12:22 +0900 Assertions            PID 140(apsd) Released InteractivePushServiceTask "com.apple.apsd-requestkeepaliveproxy-push.apple.com" 00:00:16  id:0x0x1200008dad [System: SRPrevSleep kCPU]          
2022-01-16 12:12:52 +0900 Assertions            PID 111(powerd) Released InternalPreventSleep "PM configd - Wait for Device enumeration" 00:00:45  id:0x0xd00008db0 [System: No Assertions]          
2022-01-16 12:12:52 +0900 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=disabled Using Batt (Charge:76%) 0 secs    
2022-01-16 12:12:52 +0900 Assertions            PID 240(mDNSResponder) Created MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00008db8 [System: No Assertions]          
2022-01-16 12:12:52 +0900 Assertions            PID 111(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "PM configd - Wait for Device enumeration" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00008db9 [System: No Assertions]          
2022-01-16 12:12:52 +0900 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to NUB.SPMISw3IRQ nub-spmi0.0x02 rtc/ Using BATT (Charge:76%) 45 secs   
2022-01-16 12:12:52 +0900 WakeDetails           DriverReason:NUB.SPMISw3IRQ - DriverDetails:
```

Comment: Which MacBook do you have? And which version of macOS?

Answer (score 0):

I ran the commands below and rebooted, and it was solved.

```
sudo pmset -a tcpkeepalive 0
sudo pmset -a powernap 0
sudo pmset -b standby 0
sudo pmset -a ttyskeepawake 0
```

My final setting is like below

```
$ pmset -g custom
        
Battery Power:
 Sleep On Power Button 1
 powermode            0
 standby              0
 ttyskeepawake        0
 hibernatemode        3
 powernap             0
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 displaysleep         5
 sleep                5
 tcpkeepalive         0
 lessbright           1
 disksleep            10
 SleepServices        0
AC Power:
 Sleep On Power Button 1
 powermode            0
 standby              1
 ttyskeepawake        0
 hibernatemode        3
 powernap             0
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 displaysleep         10
 womp                 0
 networkoversleep     0
 sleep                10
 tcpkeepalive         0
 disksleep            10
 SleepServices        0
```

It hasn't been resolved. The battery went down again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the problem.

When I run the iOS Simulator, this phenomenon is reproduced.
iOS Simulator keeps waking my sleeping Macbook.

Just close the iOS Simulator before the MacBook sleeps.